# Find the equation of the plane through the points and parallel

Tags: geometry

The task is the following:

```
    Find the equation of the plane trough the points P1(¡1; 2; 0); P2(¡2; 1; 1) 
    and parallel to the vector u(1; 0; 1).
```

I don't know what I am supposed to do here. Normally when I have to find the equation of a plane I have 3 vectors, I will obtain a matrix with 3 variables and then find the equation through looking for the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plane is parallel to $u$ and $v=P_2-P_1$. The exterior product $u\times v$ gives you an orthogonal vector. The coefficents of this vector are the coefficients $a,b,c$ of the equation of the plane:
$$
ax +by +cz = d.
$$
 Substitute $P_1$ to find $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. The equation of a plane becomes obvious once we know the normal vector $n$ of the plane and a particular point on the plane.
2. The normal vector $n$ is perpendicular to any vector parallel to the plane, i.e., $$n\cdot u=0$$
3. The vector $P2-P1$ is also on the plane, thus we have
   $$n\cdot <P2-P1>=0$$
4. Now the normal vector $n$ can been found. Use $$n\cdot <<x,y,z>-P1>$$ to calculate the equation of the plane.